# Firefox addon not always getting video src

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video, firefox-addon-sdk

I made trying to make my first addon but I have run into an issue. My addon is an addon to upload images and videos to a website. The images work fine, but with videos, it is a little off. Here is my code:

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Upload to domain",
  context: contextMenu.SelectorContext("img,video"),
  contentScript:'self.on("click", function(node, data){self.postMessage(node.src);});',
  onMessage: function(imgSrc){
    tabs.open("http://domain.org/upload/?"+imgSrc);
  }
});
```

If you play the video on the right [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM#Services), the video url gets passed to the onMessage function fine. If you try it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-captions), it doesn't pass a url. They are both webms. I am guessing that it just doesn't work with an html5 player. Am I correct? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method of finding source does not always work with `video` element because, unlike `img`, the `video` element's source can be specified as child element `source` which is what is happening in the second case. To handle that scenario, your code must be something like:

```
self.on("click", function(node, data){
    if(node.src){
        self.postMessage(node.src);
    }else if(node.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "video".toUpperCase()){
        var sources = node.children; // or may be node.querySelector("source");
        for(var i in sources){
            if(sources[i].src && sources[i].nodeName.toUpperCase() === "source".toUpperCase()){
                self.postMessage(node.src);
            }
        }
    }
}
```